# How to randomly secret word from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to:

1. opens a text file and read it line by line.
2. Read the lines from the file into a list.
3. Using that list of words, randomly return any word in the list

The instructor gave us this hint:

> Hint: remember to use the strip function when reading the file to
>   avoid any nasty complications arising from newline characters at the
>   end of lines.

I have to make this happen in the `get_word()` function.

As of now, I'm just  randomly selecting one of 3 words. I have to re-implement the get_word function so that instead of being hard-coded to select from a meager list of three words, it reads a much larger word
list from a file and returns a word from that list.

This is what my `get_word()` function looks like now:

```
def get_word():
    """
    This function returns a secret word that the player is trying
    to guess in the game.  This function initially has a very small
    list of words that it can select from to make it easier for you
    to write and debug the main game playing program.  In Part II of
    writing this program, you will re-implement this function to
    select a word from a much larger list by reading a list of words
    from the file specified by the constant LEXICON_FILE.
    """
    index = random.randrange(3)
    if index == 0:
        return 'HAPPY'
    elif index == 1:
        return 'PYTHON'
    else:
        return 'COMPUTER'
```

Comment: your instructions seem clear, have you attempted to open your text file and start reading from it ? where are you struggling

Comment: I've tried this so far:     lines = []
    with open("Lexicon.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()  
            lines.append(line)

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this problem is to read through the text file, appending every word to a list (you'll have to write some basic logic involving identifying words, `strip()` may come in handy here)
You can then pass that list into your `get_word` function and use `random.choice(yourList)` to obtain a random word in the text file.

Comment: Obviously I don't want to completely solve OP's problem for them, but rather guide them in the right direction, but the get_word function will look somewhat like this:
```def get_word(wordList):  
    secretWord = random.choice(wordList)   
    return secretWord```

Comment: Then include that clue in your answer. Other than that though, +1.

Answer (score 0):

this is my first answer rsrs!
Well, you can use a random lib for this:

```py
def get_word(word_list):
   import random
   print(random.choice(word_list))
```

This function now get a randomly word in the list. It's that : )

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a file with a word on each line. So then you could do something like this:

```
# write a sample file for your question...
with open('words.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('HAPPY\nPYTHON\nCOMPUTER')

import random
words = [word.strip() for word in open('words.txt').readlines()]
random_word = random.choice(words)
# 'HAPPY'
```

If it's a big file, I would suggest using the [`with ...file`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) pattern but for the above exercise I don't think that's really important.